# Parse/split nested single JSON array in Logstash

Tags: arrays, json, nested, logstash

I am looking for a splitting/filter for the following JSON-array.
We need each value in the array as an single value in elastice.

> { "Mot_Temp_Test" : { "INT" : [ "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" ] } }

Comment: You want a different document for each array element or a different field for each array element in one document?

Comment: I want a different field for each array element

Comment: [This](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-split-array-without-a-target/1590/2) could be helpful and still seems to be an issue!

Comment: @Darth_Vader OP just clarified that the is NOT what he's trying to do

Answer (score 0):

(These are results from tests I ran using logstash 2.4, output is rubydebug codec)

By using `codec => "json"` in your input logstash will actually see your array as an array. I've numbered your ints to tell them apart.

```
{
    "Mot_Temp_Test" => {
        "INT" => [
            [ 0] "0",
            [ 1] "1",
            [ 2] "2",
            [ 3] "3",
            [ 4] "4",
            [ 5] "5",
            [ 6] "6",
            [ 7] "7",
            [ 8] "8",
            [ 9] "9",
            [10] "10",
            [11] "11"
        ]
    },
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2017-01-20T16:55:42.606Z",
             "host" => "b5963373fadd"
}
```

Logstash isn't great at handling arrays, but it can access them. Thus we can use a [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split) to rename an array element to a field.

```
filter {
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int0" } }
}
```

Gives us:

```
{
    "Mot_Temp_Test" => {
        "INT" => [
            [ 0] "0",
            [ 1] "0",
            [ 2] "0",
            [ 3] "0",
            [ 4] "0",
            [ 5] "0",
            [ 6] "0",
            [ 7] "0",
            [ 8] "0",
            [ 9] "0",
            [10] "0"
        ]
    },
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2017-01-20T17:08:00.728Z",
             "host" => "5780e869e09f",
             "int0" => "0"
}
```

Okay, so this should be simple. . .

```
filter {
    mutate { 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int0" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][1]" => "int1" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][2]" => "int2" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][3]" => "int3" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][4]" => "int4" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][5]" => "int5" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][6]" => "int6" } 
    }
}
```

But wait, these operations are handled one by one and after something is removed, the array infills and we get:

```
{
    "Mot_Temp_Test" => {
        "INT" => [
            [0] "1",
            [1] "3",
            [2] "5",
            [3] "7",
            [4] "9",
            [5] "11"
        ]
    },
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2017-01-20T18:48:31.875Z",
             "host" => "a802749c44fe",
             "int0" => "0",
             "int1" => "2",
             "int2" => "4",
             "int3" => "6",
             "int4" => "8",
             "int5" => "10"
}
```

Trying to account for this:

```
filter {
    mutate { 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int0" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int1" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int2" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int3" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int4" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int5" } 
        rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int6" } 
    }
}
```

Doesn't exactly work:

```
{
                                                           "Mot_Temp_Test" => {
        "INT" => [
            [ 0] "1",
            [ 1] "2",
            [ 2] "3",
            [ 3] "4",
            [ 4] "5",
            [ 5] "6",
            [ 6] "7",
            [ 7] "8",
            [ 8] "9",
            [ 9] "10",
            [10] "11"
        ]
    },
                                                                "@version" => "1",
                                                              "@timestamp" => "2017-01-20T18:56:32.608Z",
                                                                    "host" => "d5b81003f43b",
    "\"int0\", \"int1\", \"int2\", \"int3\", \"int4\", \"int5\", \"int6\"" => "0"
}
```

To get this to work we need to use a bunch of different mutate filters:

```
filter {
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int0" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int1" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int2" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int3" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int4" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int5" } }
    mutate { rename => { "[Mot_Temp_Test][INT][0]" => "int6" } }
}
```

And success:

```
{
    "Mot_Temp_Test" => {
        "INT" => [
            [0] "7",
            [1] "8",
            [2] "9",
            [3] "10",
            [4] "11"
        ]
    },
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2017-01-20T18:21:06.488Z",
             "host" => "882832d1dd43",
             "int0" => "0",
             "int1" => "1",
             "int2" => "2",
             "int3" => "3",
             "int4" => "4",
             "int5" => "5",
             "int6" => "6"
}
```

All in all, arrays are something that logstash is not good at.